# How does the theory of the quadratic number fields relate to the quadratic forms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

As every one knows, the quadratic number fields shares a deep connection with the binary quadratic forms; I have been told this relation when I was a senior high, and now I, learning some difficult theories like the theory of fields of classes, know some basic facts about the algebraic number fields of degree two but I know nothing about what is going on in the ***Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*** by **Gauss** even though I have read it twice; it seems to be a kind of a magic there; he makes things like ideals happen with only elementary and lengthy processes. My question is the

> **Is it necessary to verify all identities in the book by Gauss to understand his theory of quadratic forms?**

I suppose it is not; then what could be said about the connection between them so that one can easily have a sight on what he is doing by modern algebraic tools?
If it was possible, please say something assertive like "The forms are just ..." Thank you very much.

Comment: For a start see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrow_class_group . This should also be discussed in Cox's _Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$._ Please do not keep commenting on your own question; I don't really see what good it's doing.

Comment: See Jay Goldman's "The Queen of Mathematics : An Historically Motivated Guide to Number Theory". It sets out the correspondence between primitive binary quadratic forms with a fundamanetal discriminant and ideals in the ring of integers of a number field. This leaves out the case of quadratic forms with general nonsquare discriminant, which will correspond to ideals classes in a proper subring of the integers of a quadratic field.

Comment: See also [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5744/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a different take, see Edwards's [Higher Arithmetic](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=STML-45).